# Refresh whole site after login Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, refresh

In Woocommerce, if a customer is a guest and is NOT logged in and visits a couple of product pages.
He does not see the prices and add to cart button. That is correct. This is like this because of this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-cart-functions/

Now the customer clicks on the account page and loges in.
Then he goes straight back to the product pages he already visited.
The problem is that he now still sees No prices and add to cart button.
The browser has saved the not logged in version of the pages and shows these to the customer after he is logged in.

The client must manually press the F5 button himself, and only then the page will reload and the prices etc. will be shown.

The only plugins I have activated are : WooCommerce, Wordfence Security and Hide Cart Functions
It does not matter which theme I use.
It does not matter if I use a plugin like Hide Cart Functions or another. They all have the same problem.
There is no other cache plugin active on the server.
There is no custom CSS.

Does anyone have any experience with this problem?
Does anyone know a way/code to automatically refresh the whole site AFTER a customer loges in?
Woocommerce does not help.

Comment: I checked the page plugin, and it's a plugin issue. The devs are aware it seems and probably are going to fix it in a later update. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/no-prices-visible-after-login-refresh-needed/

Comment: It does not matter if I use a plugin like Hide Cart Functions or another. They all have the same problem. Also, this plugin says: We don’t have a developer right now. So who knows how long this is going to take.

Comment: Then simply remove that plugin and use add / remove hooks to hide what you want based on if user is logged in or not. Another way is to set Headers for logged in users to be  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store. You can use any cache plugin from the popular list for that.

Comment: @MartinMirchev It's not that simple for me... I have hidden the whole store behind a login now, so I have a workaround for this now.